# Is the action of the matrix UU^(t) always a projection? What can I say about I - UU^t?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projective-geometry, orthogonality, projective-space

The way I understand it is that:  if U is orthogonal, i.e., its columns (or rows) form an orthonormal basis for the n-dimensional Euclidean (coordinate) space, then the matrix $UU^t$ is an orthogonal projection of vectors onto the column space of U.

But what if U were not orthogonal?  Is $UU^t$ still a projection onto the column space of U, but that the projection need not be orthogonal?  This would be my naive guess, so I'm hoping to clear up any misunderstandings I currently have.

Is the operator [I - $UU^t$] or maybe [$uu^t$-I] then an (orthogonal?) projection onto the space that is *orthogonal* to the column space of U?

Thanks,

Comment: For $P$ to be projection, it means $P^2=P$. So $UU^t$ may not be projection if $U$ is arbitrary. If $U$ is orthogonal, try to verify the definition of orthogonal projection $P^2=P, P^T=P$ for $P= I- UU^t$.

Comment: Ah, very nice, @brianding.  So, I verified that $UU^t$ as well as $I - UU^t$ are orthogonal projections / self-adjoint operators.  Now my only lingering question is...where does $I - UU^t$ project vectors onto?  My first guess would be that the range space is the space orthogonal to the column space of U, but I would like to prove this also -- either geometrically (via some vector addition) or again algebraically as you suggested just now.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: Ok, I tried just applying the operator to a vector, $( I - UU^t ) v = Iv - UU^t(v) = v - P(v)$; this vector is in the space orthogonal to the column space of U.  So, I think I have the range space correct now...for the operator $I - UU^t$.  Feel free to comment, though, @brianding.  Thanks.

Comment: $UU^T$ is **not** necessarily a projection.